# Bluetooth is not detecting devices Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless, usb, bluetooth

I have been using the Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, everything works fine in the Ubuntu except the ubuntu. The Bluetooth device is working great on the Windows 8.1 But it is failed to detect devices in the ubuntu 16.04

The Output of the  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` is

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 078: ID 045e:0797 Microsoft Corp. Optical Mouse 200
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Output of the `dmesg | grep -i blue` is

```
[   42.023723] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   42.023742] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   42.023745] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   42.023747] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   42.023758] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   42.214949] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   42.230868] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   42.230873] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   42.496550] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   42.496553] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   44.530794] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   46.890863] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   46.890865] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   46.890868] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   62.204031] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   62.204038] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   62.204043] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[21512.291179] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

Could anyone help me out